# Installing watchman when having a non-standard homebrew install

Tags: homebrew, watchman

I am using React Native which needs `watchman`. When running `react-native run-ios`, I see this error.

```
watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, 
stderr= 2017-05-05T08:17:49,256: [2110218240] while computing sockname: 
failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/foo-state: No such file or directory
```

After investigating this, it seems that it is caused by not having a standard `/usr/local/` homebrew install.

Is their a way to change the `statedir` being used by watchman?

Comment: Why would you have a non-standard homebrew install?

Comment: It's not something that I can change on my workstation.

Comment: Brew should not be installed in /opt because this causes problems in multi-user systems

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue by creating the directory and giving my user the ownership of the directory.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/var/run/watchman/foo-state
sudo chown -R myusername /usr/local/var/run/watchman/foo-state
```

Comment: This solution works well. It could be useful for React Native to support an env variable to configure `--statefile`.

Comment: Dangerous on multi-user system which is almost certainly given if user installed in home dir

Answer (score 0):

From `watchman --help`:

```
 --statefile=PATH       Specify path to file to hold watch and trigger state
```

So I think you need to use the `--statefile` option.

Comment: I am not sure how this would help because it would mean editing the script that runs the package manager in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to resolve this is to delete the state dir. Run `rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/root-state`. This resolved the same problem for me.